# Lithium PHP, MongoDB and form helpers for arrays

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I'm trying to create an edit form using Lithium to edit some MongoDB data. My data (produced by another tool) looks like this:

```
{
  "thing_a" : "value_a",
  "thing_b" : "value_b",
  "settings" : 
  {
    "sub_thing_a" : ["sub_value_a", "sub_value_b"]
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is with the array 'sub_thing_a' in 'settings'. I need to display a text box for each value so I can edit them and save them back. The ultimate aim here is to use some jQuery to add/delete text boxes to/from the form and then values from the array - but for now I'm trying to just get a simple version working that will let me edit the values and save them away.

My model is really simple:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

class Test extends \lithium\data\Model {
    protected $_meta = array('source' => 'test');
}
?>
```

and the controller likewise:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Test;

class TestsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
  public function index() {
    $tests = Test::all();
    return compact('tests');
  }

  public function edit($id=null) {  
    if(isset($id)) {
      $test = Test::find($id);
    } else {
      $test = Test::create();
    }

    if ($this->request->data) {
      if ($test->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->redirect('/tests/index');
      }
    }

    return compact('test');              
  } 
}
?>
```

Problems start with the edit form - As I have it now, it will display the values of my array, but the data does not get written correctly. Any clues as to how I should approach this? (Note: As I mentioned earlier, I will need to produce a dynamic version of this that allows me to add/delete text boxes to/from the form, so I do need to be able to take some sort of control of the helper - in case there is some really easy 'convention' way of doing this.)

edit.html.php:

```
<?=$this->form->create($test); ?>
<?=$this->form->field('thing_a'); ?>

<?php foreach ($test->settings->sub_thing_a as $i=>$elem): ?>

<?=$this->form->field('settings.sub_thing_a',array('label'=>'thing', 'value'=>$test->settings->sub_thing_a[$i]));?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?=$this->form->submit('save'); ?>
<?=$this->form->end(); ?>
```

and index.html.php (for completeness)

```
<?php foreach($tests as $test): ?>

<h2><?=$this->html->link($test->thing_a,'/tests/edit/'.$test->_id); ?></h2>

    <?php foreach($test->settings->sub_thing_a as $item): ?>

<h4><?=$item ?></h4>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so in the end, it was (of course) quite simple. in the edit.html.php file we can simply write:

```
<?=$this->form->field('settings[sub_thing_a][]',array('value'=>$test->settings->sub_thing_a[$i]));?>
```

The settings[sub_thing_a][] creates the array containing an array of the string values from the form.